# How large are the smallest-area projections of a high-dimensional convex body?

Tags: convexity, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $B$ be a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^d$, equipped with its standard Euclidean form, and assume that

$$\intop_B x \, dx = 0$$
$$\frac{1}{|B|_d} \intop_B x_i x_j \, dx = \delta_{ij},$$

a normalization that can always be achieved by an appropriate affine transformation. Here $|\cdot|_d$ means $d$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, of course.

Now let's look at the areas of $(d-1)$-dimensional projections of $B$. It's clear that

$$ \inf_{\Vert \xi \Vert = 1} \frac{|\mathrm{pr}_{\xi^\perp} B|_{d-1}}{|B|_d} \le c_d,$$

where $c_d$ is some universal constant, depending only on dimension.

**Question:** is it true that

$$\lim_{d \to \infty} c_d < \infty$$

As far as I know, the answer is [known to be negative](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201204) if instead of second-moment normalization as above we use a volume normalization (i.e. $|B|_d=1$).

Comment: Is this false with $\sup$ instead of $\inf$?

Comment: @WillSawin: Yes, for the $d$-dimensional cube the largest projection has area of order $\sqrt d$.

Comment: Are you sure you have the right expression?  The homogeneity looks funny.

Comment: @MarkMeckes: Homogeneity is not an issue here exactly because of the second moment normalization, i.e. I'm fixing the "width" of the set in any direction.

Comment: @MarkMeckes: What I wrote at the bottom line made no sense exactly for the reason that you indicated. Please see the updated version.

Comment: Among the (normalized) spheres, one actually gets a limit $1/\sqrt{\pi}$ as $d\to\infty$.

Comment: @PietroMajer: $1/\sqrt{2 \pi}$, I believe. Anyway, $\ell^p$ balls are are certainly not counterexamples.

Comment: yes,  $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ .